# How to forward catch-all emails to another domain/email with postfix?

Tags: linux, debian, postfix

I am totally newbie with email postfix (any email server) but I would like to do this:

```
Example:
- all incoming emails for @domena1.sk forward to ciel@domena2.sk
- all incoming emails for @domena3.sk forward to ciel@domena4.sk
- all incoming emails for ujo@dom.sk forward to new@dom20.sk
- all incoming emails for repa@dom.sk forward to old@dom20.sk
```

And I need to configure this email server just for this - so it should prevent using it in any other manner (prevent misuse for spam). As I said I have no experience with setting this up so I would really appreciate step by step guide for this.

Comment: Postfix can do this, and there are a number of HOWTO guides at www.postfix.org.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by inserting a

```
@domain.from: @domain.to
```

line into your virtual aliased map, which is in most cases in /etc/postfix/virtual.

After that, you shouldn't forget to rerun a

```
postmap virtual
```

command to recreate its database!

Comment: thank you! now I just need to secure postfix agains unauthorized spammers (so it should not be able to accept any attempt for sending email from outside) (so only forwarding allowed) If any "how to" idea, much appreciated.